# Restore website using Akeeba backup downloaded file

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

I backed up my website using Akeeba backup and downloaded the jpa file. I now need to restore that backup. The backup is not displayed amongst the files in the file manager within Akeeba but thankfully I have the downloaded file. But I do not know how to use this file to restore. There is no option within the Akeeba interface to upload the jpa file. How do i do it?? Any help would be great. Also I am using Joomla 3

Comment: https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/restoring-backups.html

Comment: In the link above, skip to the Akeeba Kickstart section. It should have all the information you need.

Comment: Please read the documentation on the Akeeba site. The backup component is specifically to "backup" your website. You'll need to use Akeeba Kickstart to restore the backup.

Comment: there is a video in youtube made by akeeba, watch that

Comment: Please accept the answer given - it is correct. @alan-mc

Answer (score 3):

You need do this steps:

1. Upload your .jpa file;
2. Upload the file kickstart.php from Akeeba site in same directory .jpa file. 
   https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html
3. Run the file www.yoursite.com/kickstart.php
4. Follow steps from restore process.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please be aware that as you run the Akeeba Kickstart, any current site files in the same directory will be replaced.